# ¿Cómo agregar un usuario a la base de datos de Firebase después de crearlo?

Tags: firebase, reactjs

Estoy empezando con Firebase y con React y la idea de mi aplicación es crear un sistema de autenticación con Firebase, pero quiero guardar los usuarios que cree en la base de datos e identificarlos con la `id` que genera Firebase, pero cuando los creo la página se refresca y no se guardan en la base de datos, solo se crean en el apartado de autenticación.

La manera como lo estoy haciendo es la siguiente:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import firebase from './firebase.js'

export default class CreacionUsuario extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email:'',
            contraseña:'',
            nombre: '',
            edad: '',
            peso: '',
            estatura:''
        }
        this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    handleSubmit(e){
        console.log(this.state)
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.contraseña)
        .then(()=>{
            var user=firebase.auth().currentUser
            console.log(user)
            firebase.database.ref().child('/usuario/'+user.uid).update({
                email: this.state.email,
                nombre: this.state.nombre,
                edad: this.state.edad,
                peso: this.state.peso,
                estatura: this.state.estatura
            })
        })
    }
    handleInput(e){
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <form>
              Email: <br />
              <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handleInput}/><br />
              Contraseña: <br />
              <input type="password" name="contraseña" onChange={this.handleInput}/><br />
              Nombre: <br />
              <input type="text" name="nombre" onChange={this.handleInput}/><br />
              Edad: <br />
              <input type="text" name="edad" onChange={this.handleInput}/><br />
              Peso: <br />
              <input type="text" name="peso" onChange={this.handleInput}/><br />
              Estatura: <br />
              <input type="text" name="estatura" onChange={this.handleInput}/><br /><br />
              <input type="submit" value="Crear" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error simplemente esta en esta linea:

`firebase.database.ref().child('/usuario/'+user.uid).update({...})`

estas usando /usuario/ cuando deberia ser usuario/ de todas formas yo la cambiaria por:

`firebase.database.ref('usuario').child(user.uid).update({...})`

Tambien probaria cambiar el update por un set.